# TRACKER : error TRK0005: Failed to locate: "CL.exe". The system cannot find the file specified. (vxcproj)

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-gyp

**I have Visual Studio 2017 Community installed along with BuildTools 2017, and the VS2017 Redistruables & Required Python versions. And have set the ms_vs config to 2017. But yet still it comes up with this error installing whatever npm package that requires node-gyp. And I already have node-gyp installed. NPM-V: 6.4.1 - 10.15.2 LTS**